# How to properly use "reference database"?

Tags: word-order

Does it make more sense to say

> a reference database of [somethings]

or

> a [something] reference database

For example, by replacing [something] with "library" we get:

> a reference database of libraries

or

> a library reference database

So which is more proper? Or does it matter?

Comment: I expect the vast majority of references to *reference database* would lose no meaning whatsoever if they dropped the word *reference*. For the rest, it doesn't really matter whether the type of information being referenced comes before or after *reference database* in the name of the data source.

Comment: @FumbleFingers are you saying that reference database is redundant?

Comment: @yydl - unless this is a special database that has some special status as the single authoritative store of the information compared to all the other sources then yes it's redundant

Comment: @MartinBeckett I wouldn't say *single* authoritative, but yes, authoritative. In other words, similar in meaning to "encyclopedia"

Comment: It's standard terminology in crosswordland to specify the *reference dictionary* for really tough puzzles if the compiler actually restricts himself to a single one. In the UK it's often *Chambers*, which was also the original reference dictionary for UK [Official Scrabble Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble)

Answer (score 2):

```
a reference database of libraries
```

or

```
a library reference database
```

May actually mean different things.  A reference database of libraries could be a database holding library information while a library reference database could be a reference database used by the library and may be on any number of topics.  I would agree with the commenters that "reference" may be a redundant word.

My local state university uses the following syntax when describing databases which would be useful for General Business topics:

```
Key resources for General Business
> Recommended databases to start your search
Show all General Business databases
```